# How do I edit .xslm file in ruby/rails without losing VBA macros?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, vba

I have some .xslm files in my project which I have to edit. My application is written in Rails. I know macro enabled files can not be edited with rubyXL or roo gem, somehow I have to edit them using Ruby/Rails gems or any tool which can be incorporated within Rails app. The application is hosted on AWS, does aws have any tool to do the same ?  Plus the requirement is the macros be retained.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is not possible to edit macro enabled excel sheets (.xlsm) files in Rails. Even though you tweaked the file somehow, MS Office will treat it as a corrupt file.